# Pro Grids Not showing in package manager unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image: Unity screen shot]

Progrids is not showing in unity package manager and I am not able to import it into the projects

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a simpler way to get ProGrids to show up in 2018.3: Just enable Advanced > Show preview packages in the Package Manager.

Comment: Bloody ridiculous.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

ProGrid is not supported in newer versions since they built-in enough of ProGrid features.